# Terminal doesn't find nvim command altough it is installed

Tags: command-line, package-management

I have installed nvim with brew (because the version I got with apt was not working with treesitter).
Everything was working fine but after a restart, my terminal didn't know the nvim and brew commands.
I get this error:

> zsh: command not found: nvim

That is how I installed brew and nvim

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

If I repeat that process, it shows me that nvim is already installed and then I can use the command but once I restart, it's gone again.

I'm not so familiar with Ubuntu yet so if you need more information to help me, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have missed this part:

```bsh
- Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
    echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ${HOME}/.zprofile
    eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Do the first one so zsh can initialize the right environment variables.